# 1963 home New Zealand electrical wiring question

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding

I have a house that was built in 1963. I was sure the wiring was upgraded at one point. I went to install a new switch in my daughter's room and found exposed twisted copper running to the earth terminal.

I figured it was an earth bonding wire, however, should it be used as earthing for a power outlet? Granted the outlet has a switch on it.

You guys reckon I should just get someone in to rewire?

Comment: historibally cable had a with non-insulated earth wires that was used for earth bonding, but now the cables have an insulated wire. Switch? You can't put a general purpose outlet on a lighting circuit.  A photo would help.

Comment: @Jasen I will get one up asap. I realized after posting, probably best to get a photo up.

Comment: The requirement to insulate the earth came in sometime after then, I think. Bare earths are to be expected. It's moderately unlikely that the wiring would have been replaced in a 1963 house as that's recent enough that it would be plastic cable, not rubber.